# programmatically set win forms user controls to nothing on dispose

Tags: vb.net, winforms, reflection, memory-leaks

I have vb.net winforms application. It has memory leaks which is caused by a third party control. I am left with the option of reducing instead of eliminating the memory leaks.

The form has several user controls declared as Friend WithEvents. They are not GCed when the form is closed, because the form is in memory and it holds a reference to the user control. However, when I set the user control references to nothing on dispose, the memory leak is reduced.

Now I want to expand this to the whole application instead of just one form. How would I use reflection to scan through all the user controls and set them to nothing on dispose ? Interesting to note is that the user controls are declared using "Friend WithEvents" signature. Is it possible to somehow use this while scanning ?

Comment: You dont need reflection, just `Dispose` of any controls you create.  If the other things is an actual UserControl, disposing of its child controls is built in (unless they are also doing dynamic controls)

Answer (score 1):

As @Plutonix states, if you dispose of the control, it will invalidate and dispose of its child controls. If you believe they are using dynamic controls, you could just recursively dispose of the controls?

```
Sub DisposeControls(parentControl as Control)
    For each control as Control in parentControl.Controls 
        If control.HasChildren() Then Call Me.DisposeControls(control) 
        control.Dispose()
    Next
End Sub
```

Edit: should mention, I am unsure if code above will compile - treat as pseudocode.

Comment: the code is solid, but it doesnt help with the memory problem. It still doesnt give the memory reduction that setting the user control refs to null gives

Comment: That is really interesting! It could be that the 3rd party control library has overridden the base functionality of dispose, and hasn't implemented the CloseHandle as per this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3) article to dispose of the unmanaged resources. Thanks for adding your answer as a solution, good to see how you achieved the result!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this. Its not optimal but it works really well. I have all the forms inheriting a base form. In the disposed method of that form, I use this reflection code.

```
Private Sub BaseForm_Disposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Disposed
    NullifyReferencesOnDispose()
    RemoveHandler Me.Disposed, AddressOf BaseForm_Disposed
End Sub

Protected Overridable Sub NullifyReferencesOnDispose()
    Dim typ = CType(Me.GetType, Reflection.TypeInfo)
    For Each fld In typ.DeclaredFields
        fld.SetValue(Me, Nothing)
    Next
End Sub
```